# Data present in rows to columns

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a scenario, where in, I've a table with records:

```
AppNo   Location    Department  Code
1       NY          XYZ         1
1       NY          ABC         2
1       NY          PQR         3
2       TX          XYZ         1
2       TX          ABC         2
```

There can be multiple rows(Maximum 5) with same AppNo and Location with different Department and Code values.

we need a Stored procedure which fetches data in below manner:

```
AppNo   Location    Department  Code    Location    Department  Code    Location    Department  Code    Location    Department  Code    Location    Department  Code
1       NY          XYZ         1       NY          ABC         2       NY          PQR         3       
2       TX          XYZ         1       TX          ABC         2
```

Basically, for each AppNo, we need data in a single row, with the columns repeated.

Please suggest me some ways to accomplish this.

Thanks in advance, Krishna

Comment: it will be better if u manipulate retrieves data further with help of PHP or whatever scripting language you use.

Comment: @JW OP said max 5 rows

Comment: It's easy. But need Time. **:)**. Let me try.

Comment: @Luv, I'll be waiting for your idea of approach :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no PIVOT command in MySQL, but there are workarounds - [Pivot table basics: rows to columns...](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#78), [MySQL pivot tables (transform rows to columns)](http://buysql.com/mysql/12-how-to-pivot-tables.html).

For your case you could use something like this -

```
SELECT AppNo,
  MAX(IF(code = 1, Location, NULL)) Location,
  MAX(IF(code = 1, Department, NULL)) Department,
  1 Code1,
  MAX(IF(code = 2, Location, NULL)) Location,
  MAX(IF(code = 2, Department, NULL)) Department,
  2 Code2,
  MAX(IF(code = 3, Location, NULL)) Location,
  MAX(IF(code = 3, Department, NULL)) Department,
  3 Code3,
  MAX(IF(code = 4, Location, NULL)) Location,
  MAX(IF(code = 4, Department, NULL)) Department,
  4 Code4,
  MAX(IF(code = 5, Location, NULL)) Location,
  MAX(IF(code = 5, Department, NULL)) Department,
  5 Code5
FROM <table name>
GROUP BY AppNo
```

P.S. You can run this query from the stored routine.

Comment: Hi Devart, thanks for providing solution. I'm trying to analyse it, could you pls. explain why you are using 1 Code1, 2 Code2, 3 Code3 in the query. If you can let me know how it is working in the query then it would be ver helpful.. Thanks again!!!

Comment: There are examples and explanations on added links (pivot). About the - 1 Code1, 2 Code2, 3 Code3... the field names have to be different.

Answer (score 0):

Procedure will work on `sql server 2008 r2` (Don't have any knowledge in `MYSQL` and i am **weak** in it.)

```
--EXEC ABC
CREATE PROCEDURE ABC
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY

        if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#app') is not null
        begin
            drop table #app
        end

        create table #app
        (
            AppNo int,
            Location varchar(10),
            Department varchar(10),
            Code int
        )

        insert into #app
        values
        (1       ,'NY'          ,'XYZ1'     ,    1),
        (1       ,'NY'          ,'ABC1'     ,    2),
        (1       ,'NY'          ,'PQR1'     ,    3),
        (2       ,'TX'          ,'XYZ'     ,    1),
        (2       ,'TX'          ,'ABC'     ,    2)

        --select * from #app

        if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#t') is not null
        begin
            drop table #t
        end

        create table #t
        (
            AppNo int,
            Location1 varchar(10),
            Department1 varchar(10),
            Code1 int,
            Location2 varchar(10),
            Department2 varchar(10),
            Code2 int,
            Location3 varchar(10),
            Department3 varchar(10),
            Code3 int,
            Location4 varchar(10),
            Department4 varchar(10),
            Code4 int,
            Location5 varchar(10),
            Department5 varchar(10),
            Code5 int,
        )

        insert into #t
        (   
            AppNo,
            Location1,
            Department1,
            Code1,
            Location2,
            Department2,
            Code2,
            Location3,
            Department3,
            Code3,
            Location4,
            Department4,
            Code4,
            Location5,
            Department5,
            Code5
        )

        select 
            DISTINCT
            A.AppNo AS AppNo,
            A1.Location AS Location1,
            A1.Department AS Department1,
            A1.Code AS Code1,
            A2.Location AS Location1,
            A2.Department AS Department1,
            A2.Code AS Code1,
            A3.Location AS Location1,
            A3.Department AS Department1,
            A3.Code AS Code1,
            A4.Location AS Location1,
            A4.Department AS Department1,
            A4.Code AS Code1,
            A5.Location AS Location1,
            A5.Department AS Department1,
            A5.Code AS Code1
        from #app A
        INNER JOIN #app A1 ON A.AppNo=A1.AppNo AND A1.Code=1
        LEFT JOIN #app A2 ON A.AppNo=A2.AppNo AND A2.Code=2
        LEFT JOIN #app A3 ON A.AppNo=A3.AppNo AND A3.Code=3
        LEFT JOIN #app A4 ON A.AppNo=A4.AppNo AND A4.Code=4
        LEFT JOIN #app A5 ON A.AppNo=A5.AppNo AND A5.Code=5

        SELECT * FROM #t
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        --YOUR ERROR
    END CATCH
END
```