# tsql left outer join with multiple records displayed on a single line

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

Hi I have two table with a 1-N relationship where N is maximum 3. A Group has at least 1 user and a maximum of 3 users. I would like to display the group and all possible users on a single row with a select query.

Group :

```
ID  Name
1   Group1
2   Group2
```

Users :

```
ID  Username IDGroup
1   User1    1
2   User2    2
3   User3    1
4   User4    1
```

Result (Where no Username to display it's ok null or empty string) :

```
IDGroup GroupName Username1 Username2 Username3
1       Group1    User1     User3     User4
2       Group2    User2     Null      Null
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible since the number of column in the result will be changed base on the number of user in the group. Why don't you just display it as each user per row using simple inner join?

Comment: No the number of column will always be the same (5) because there will be no more than 3 users per group. And I need this layout because of a business specific application.

Comment: I will get back to you. but can u tell me max no. of ID in a IDGroup.

Comment: Thanks ! Yes maximum 3 users per group (also if it's possible display the top 3 users in this group regardless of the number of possible users in a group)

Comment: I have submitted a similar **[answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15757207/data-present-in-rows-to-columns/15759973#15759973)**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Pivot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).

```
select P.IDGroup,
       P.GroupName,
       P.[1] as Username1,
       P.[2] as Username2,
       P.[3] as Username3
from 
  (
  select G.ID as IDGroup,
         G.Name as GroupName,
         U.Username,
         row_number() over(partition by G.ID order by U.Username) as rn
  from Groups as G
    left outer join Users as U
      on G.ID = U.IDGroup
  ) as T
pivot
  (
  max(T.Username) for T.rn in ([1],[2],[3])
  ) as P
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/85244/1)

**Update:**

If there are more fields that is needed I would do it like this instead.

```
select T.IDGroup,
       T.GroupName,
       max(case when T.rn = 1 then T.Username end) as Username1,
       max(case when T.rn = 1 then T.Email end) as Email1,
       max(case when T.rn = 2 then T.Username end) as Username2,
       max(case when T.rn = 2 then T.Email end) as Email2,
       max(case when T.rn = 3 then T.Username end) as Username3,
       max(case when T.rn = 3 then T.Email end) as Email3
from (
     select G.ID as IDGroup,
            G.Name as GroupName,
            U.Username,
            U.Email,
            row_number() over(partition by G.ID order by U.Username) as rn
     from Groups as G
       left outer join Users as U
         on G.ID = U.IDGroup
     ) as T
group by T.IDGroup,
         T.GroupName
```

Comment: Thank you I've never heard of pivot before and it's a real life saver ! Thanks a bunch !

Comment: Just an additional question if you don't mind. I also have an email field in the User table. How would I display this additionally to the username using the pivot ?

Comment: @Arno2501 Ok, I see you already got that one sorted, +1 to you then.

Answer (score 1):

I also want to provide this answer as it is also good and in my opinion more flexible if you want to add additional fields :

```
select  
        T.IDGroup
       ,T.GroupName
       ,[1] = max(case when rn = 1 then T.Username end)
       ,[2] = max(case when rn = 2 then T.Username end)
       ,[3] = max(case when rn = 3 then T.Username end)
from 
  (
  select G.ID as IDGroup,
         G.Name as GroupName,
         U.Username,
         row_number() over(partition by G.ID order by U.Username) as rn
  from Groups as G
    left outer join Users as U
      on G.ID = U.IDGroup
  ) as T
group by T.IDGroup, T.GroupName
```